# In binary classification, what label imbalance is acceptable to not to care?

Tags: classification, binary-data

I have a pretty large set of binary-labeled data (~20K rows, ~100 columns). Approximately 20% of the data is "positive" and 80% is "negative". In my case every classification error has the same meaning.  Is this misbalance big enough in order to take special measures such as differential weighting and/or differential sampling. Is there any rule of thumb? Or maybe a publication? Does the answer to this question depend on the classification algorithm?